# Consider the cylinder $(x-a)^2+y^2=1$. Describe a curve that is (a) asymptotic curve (b) line of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the cylinder $(x-a)^2+y^2=1$. Describe a curve that is

(a) asymptotic curve
(b) line of curvature

I don't understand what the problem means, if you want me to parameterize the cylinder and calculate.

Could you say that the meridians of the cylinder are lines of curvature?

Comment: How do you not understand? You should understand these concepts well enough to see the answer without calculating. My question is this: Do they want one curve that satisfies both (a) and (b)?

Comment: @TedShifrin I parameterized the cylinder as $(a+\cos u,\, \sin u, v)$, so the $v$ curves are necessarily asymptotic curves and they are also lines of curvature. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, well done!

Comment: @TedShifrin Now I want to do it calculating. First, we find the main address. For it to be principal direction it must satisfy a certain differential equation in terms of the coefficients of the first and second fundamental form. I am left with $dudv=0$. What do I do?

Comment: So either $du=0$ ($v$-curves) or $dv=0$ ($u$-curves).